# Not sure about what i understood about SSO / NTLM / Windows auth

Tags: internet-explorer, single-sign-on, ntlm

I'm working on an intranet application.
I would like to connect the user w/o any form, so with his windows login.
So I guess I have to use Windows auth.

Is Windows authentication and NTLM the same thing ?
Does it always ask the user to enter login/password ? because, i have enabled Windows auth on my website (and disabled others auth!) but when I go to the website, it asks me login/password in a pop up and what ever I type, it gives me error 401.

So, is it possible to do what I want to ?
And please, do you have any links to do it with IIS server on Internet explorer because i'm having a really hard time to find (and understand) informations on it :[

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through this [link](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication) for information about Windows authentication.

You need to add your website URL to Tools->Internet Options-> security-> Local Intranet. This will enable the browser to pass the NTLM/Kerberos (windows Authn) token. The login popup you are seeing is cause your Windows Authentication failed and it fallbacked to "Basic" Authentication which is expected behavior.